# Apache Flink with Docker Swarm cannot register TaskManager to JobManager's Resource Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-flink, docker-swarm

I am having a trouble when deploying Apache Flink 1.16.1 on 2 Google Cloud instances with Docker Swarm. The JobManager is deployed on the manager node and the TaskManager is deployed in the worker node. The TaskManager seems to have a trouble to communicate with ResourceManager  on JobManager via akka.tcp.

```
flink_taskmanager.1.e7sxy43lsb49@workernode.gcp    | 2023-03-29 13:50:34,061 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.DefaultJobLeaderService [] - Start job leader service.
flink_taskmanager.1.e7sxy43lsb49@workernode.gcp    | 2023-03-29 13:50:34,066 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.filecache.FileCache                 [] - User file cache uses directory /tmp/flink-dist-cache-705fdca5-c285-4875-9b68-556ccd1b56c3
flink_taskmanager.1.e7sxy43lsb49@workernode.gcp    | 2023-03-29 13:50:34,073 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Connecting to ResourceManager akka.tcp://flink@jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_*(00000000000000000000000000000000).
flink_taskmanager.1.e7sxy43lsb49@workernode.gcp    | 2023-03-29 13:50:34,420 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Resolved ResourceManager address, beginning registration
flink_taskmanager.1.e7sxy43lsb49@workernode.gcp    | 2023-03-29 13:55:34,086 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor           [] - Fatal error occurred in TaskExecutor akka.tcp://flink@10.0.1.14:6127/user/rpc/taskmanager_0.
flink_taskmanager.1.e7sxy43lsb49@workernode.gcp    | org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.exceptions.RegistrationTimeoutException: Could not register at the ResourceManager within the specified maximum registration duration PT5M. This indicates a problem with this instance. Terminating now.
```

About firewall rules, these instances are deployed in the same VPC, same subnet, so I suppose it can communicate without any troubles. In fact, I can ping or curl on both instances.
Before deploying to Google Cloud, I have successfully deployed the same setup on my private Microstack cloud without any problem. Here is my docker-compose file that I used `docker stack deploy`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  jobmanager:
    image: halo93/fixed-ports-flink-docker:1.16.1-scala_2.12-java11-custom
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == managernode.gcp]
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "6123:6123"
      - "6124:6124"
      - "6125:6125"
    command: jobmanager
    environment:
      - FLINK_PROPERTIES=${FLINK_PROPERTIES}
    networks:
      - flink-network
  taskmanager:
    image: halo93/fixed-ports-flink-docker:1.16.1-scala_2.12-java11-custom
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.hostname == workernode.gcp]
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    ports:
      - "6121:6121"
      - "6122:6122"
      - "6126:6126"
      - "6127:6127"
      - "6128:6128"
      - "5005:5005/udp"
    command:
      - taskmanager
    environment:
      - FLINK_PROPERTIES=${FLINK_PROPERTIES}
    networks:
      - flink-network

networks:
  flink-network:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

FLINK_PROPERTIES

```
FLINK_PROPERTIES=$'\njobmanager.rpc.address: jobmanager\nparallelism.default: 2\n'
```

I am using a customized flink docker image to fix taskmanager.data.port and taskmanager.rpc.port to 6126 and 6127.
I have tried to change jobmanager.rpc.address with the private IP and zonal DNS, ResourceManager can register the taskmanager. However, by doing so, flink-metrics is unable to work. I expect that I can successfully deploy flink cluster on Google Cloud instances with Docker Swarm, same with what I did on Microstack
Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I would be really appreciated.

Comment: After spending days on debugging, I have figured out that this problem is related to the mismatched number of MTU between docker swarm overlay network and the network interface of the GCP instance. On my Microstack instances, the MTU is 1500 which is equal to the default MTU of the overlay network. On GCP side, the instance's network interface MTU is 1460, so using the overlay network's default MTU will cause all akka tcp packets between containers in nodes dropped. Changing the overlay network's MTU to 1450 fixed my problem :)